# htaccess https rediraction from non-www to www

Tags: php, .htaccess, ssl

Here is the issue;
The page I faced with problem is https://gomlekchim.com/.

If you are using chrome or some other browser, it will alert you with SSL Error. That is normal because we only have certificate for www domain. So, what I need is to directing this page to a www page which is http//www.gomlekchim.com. That page might be http or https. Either works for me.

Comment: So now we know what you want, but we don't know what your question is...

Comment: @marcell-fulop I want to redirect (https://gomlekchim.com) to (https://www.gomlekchim.com)

Comment: As said above, it's clear what you _want_. Show what you've tried and explain how it's failing. Then we can help.

Comment: If you visit https://gomlekchim.com/ , It gives SSL error at chrome for instance.

Comment: RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
this is my rediraction code for http pages. I need same something for https pages. @marcell-fulop

Answer (score 1):

I didn't test it but this should work

```
Options +FollowSymLinks 

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.gomlekchim\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.gomlekchim.com/$1 [R=301,L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.gomlekchim\.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.gomlekchim.com/$1 [R=301,L,QSA]
```